# Visual Studio Code: terminal input accents (java.util.Scanner)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, diacritics

I wrote a very simple Java program and, trying to input a string with some accents, I noticed that Scanner (or the terminal) has issues to handle them.

I don't know how to resolve this problem with encoding.

#### Code

```
    System.out.println("aeíóu"); // output => aeíóu

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
    String str = input.nextLine(); // input => aeíóu
    input.close();
    System.out.println(str); // output => ae  u
```

#### Outputs (Visual Studio Code)

- Java Process Console:

  [image]
- cmd:

  [image]

#### Enviroment

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- JDK: 1.8.0_231
- Visual Studio Code: 1.39.2

Comment: try to set  `"files.autoGuessEncoding":true` in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be any help, it is a while since I have tested this in Windows and if Microsoft has fixed the issue or made improvements (or if the JVM has made any changes to how the unicode is outputted):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/

The problem was (or still is?) that the windows console could not be reliably used for input and output of unicode from applications that use the C standard library (byte) I/O functions. This includes Java too. The codepage 65001 was broken.

Not sure if the above post can point you in the right direction though.